# Can't figure out how to import modules in browser with javascript

Tags: javascript, module, es6-modules

This is a simple problem. I'm attempting to import modules from one javascript file to another, and then run it on Chrome. I'm using 2 javascript files and an html file, all in the same folder:

first js file (testfile1.js):

```
import {test} from 'testfile2.js';

test.func();
```

second js file (testfile2.js):

```
let f = function() {
  console.log("TEST");
}

let test = {
  func: f
};

export test;
```

The html file is plain, empty html file with a link to testfile1.js script in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="testfile1.js"></script>
```

Whenever I open the html file in chrome, I get the error:

```
testfile1.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

When I removed the brackets in the import statement, I get an unexpected identifier statement. Isn't this the proper way to import modules in the browser? Why is it not working at all?

Comment: `type="module"` as per [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) - or you can use *function-like dynamic import()* - again as per that documentation

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## Modules require `type="module"` not `"text/javascript"`

As per Jaromanda X's comment, you need to change the value of the `<script>` tag's `type` attribute to `"module"` because `import { test } from 'testfile2.js'` is module code.

```
<script type="module" src="testfile1.js" />
```

#### What about dynamic `import()`

If you really don't feel like using `type="module"`, any JavaScript file is allowed to use the dynamic `import()` syntax, even without `type="module"`.

However, the dynamic import has a caveat; the function `import()` returns a promise, therefore, you are unable to use it synchronously. You must either `await` or `.then` a dynamic import to use the value it resolves to.

```
import('testfile2.js').then(({ test }) => {
  // your code
});
```