# Is <script src=""></script> the right way to use JavaScript libraries in a front-end project?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

For a lot of JavaScript projects, such as Bootstrap (well you may argue that it is just a CSS framework, anyway this is not the point), the [installation section](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/download/) comes two ways.

The first way is usually like this:

```
npm install bootstrap
```

and the second way is the one I know:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

My understanding is that `npm` is the right way to go if I am using `node.js` to do back-end development. Suppose I am using other backends (say, Python, Java) and JavaScript is run only on the client's browser, I should stick with the `<script src=""></script>` approach. Is this generally correct?

Another closely related question is about the use of import statement, such as `import bootstrap from 'bootstrap'`. My understanding is that this syntax only works for the `node.js` backend and I cannot use it on an HTML page without a lot of extra effort. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't figure out how to import modules in browser with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55310227/cant-figure-out-how-to-import-modules-in-browser-with-javascript)

Comment: I don't see how `<script src=""` would be affected by the backend technology. That is just pure HTML feature to load a JavaScript file. If you don't use that, you don't have many other options. You'd probably have to dynamically generate the HTML source and have the JS pasted in it but I can't see why you'd want that.

Comment: @VLAZ I don't see how you interpret my question this way.

Comment: @Mamsds how am I supposed to read it? You asked whether you should use script tags with a source attribute with a different backend language. If that's not what you asked, then what did you ask related to script tags with source attributes and backend languages?

Comment: @VLAZ if you are unhappy about the way I ask or if you think the question is too simple for you to answer, you may leave. "I don't see how <script src="" would be affected by the backend technology. " -> I don't see how it contributes to the discussion.

Comment: My question is what *is* the discussion? What other way of using script files would there be based on the backend technology? In order to ask this question, I'd expect you have some sort of alternative in mind.

Comment: @VLAZ "My question is what is the discussion?" -> I don't see why you'd want that.    I think the best thing you can do is to leave this question to other people.

Comment: @Mamsds you're not being very nice.

Comment: @Mamsds - please keep it cool! `I should stick with the <script src=""></script> approach. Is this generally correct?` - yes

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Hi prof, this actually leads to my second question: for my current project, I have to import two libraries, <script src="./lib/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script> and <script src="./lib/react/17.0.2/umd/react.dev.js"></script></script>. If I get it right, I am essentially using label to "compile" react in clients' browser, is this the right way to go if I need to use react inside an HTML page?..

Comment: @Mamsds - As a long-standing member of this community, my advice is to tone it down in the comments and assume good will from others. Telling people to go away is never a good idea. VLAZ is asking reasonable questions based on his read of your question while trying to help you. (He's a very helpful person.) Remember that English is not everyone's first language.

Answer (score 7):

> My understanding is that npm is the right way to go if I am using node.js to do back-end development.

That **used** to be true, but these days lots of web projects have a build step using a bundler (Webpack, Rollup, Vite, Parcel, ...) and those bundlers can bundle web-compatible `npm` packages into your client-side code, creating optimized files (including the relevant parts of those `npm` packages) that you then use as your frontend code.

The `script` solution is the fundamental way you do this without a bundler.

> Another closely related question is about the use of import statement, such as import bootstrap from 'bootstrap'. My understanding is that this syntax only works for the node.js backend...

That's no longer true, although you need a path on the module specifier (`from "./somefile.js"`) or an [import map](https://wicg.github.io/import-maps/) *(new, experimental, but maturing)* when using this in browser-based code. All modern browsers support modules natively now.

Comment: For my current project, I have to import two libraries, `<script src="./lib/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>` and `<script src="./lib/react/17.0.2/umd/react.dev.js"></script></script>`. If I get it right, I am essentially using label to "compile" react, is this the right way to go if I need to use react inside an html page?..

Comment: @Mamsds - You can use React that way (including the UMD script and then using things from the `React` global it creates). I would recommend not using [Babel standalone](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-standalone) in a *production* project though. From that link: *"If you're using Babel in production, you should normally not use @babel/standalone. Instead, you should use a build system running on Node.js, such as Webpack, Rollup, or Parcel, to transpile your JS ahead of time."* If you want to avoid a build step, I would just [not use JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html).

Comment: Thanks @T.J. Crowder. after reading your comment and checking the link, my understanding is that, originally, React uses a JavaScript extension called JSX which is not directly supported by browsers. To make JSX compatible to browsers, we need a "translator", that is, the Babel library. Is this what you said?

Comment: @Mamsds - I don't know whether React used JSX "initially," but yes, JSX is the way most people use React, and yes JSX is not currently supported directly by the JavaScript engines in browsers, so you need to compile (sometimes people say "transpile") code using JSX before running it in the browser. That's often where bundlers come into it, because they can run Babel at build time and include its output in the bundle.

Comment: Hi @T.J. Crowder. This leads to my next question... Say I am willing to use `npm` and I get bootstrap, react or whatever packages installed, then what's next?.. How can I "embed" the packages I installed on my server to an HTML page?..

Comment: @Mamsds - With a bundler.

Comment: Hi @T.J. Crowder, I guess I finally get the point--the idea is, say I use `npm` packages in my "source" HTML files, JS files, then I use bundler to compile/transpile the "source" HTML/JS files which a browser cannot interpret into the "destination" HTML/JS files which a browser can interpret. When serving the Internet, I use the destination files. Is this the over all idea?

Comment: @Mamsds - Yes, that's it. I'm a big fan of keeping it simple (no build step, or a build step only in production to remove comments, etc.), but if you're doing React and you want to use JSX, a build step is necessary, so at that point you may as well get the other benefits of using a bundler. (That's what I do on my React and [Preact](https://preactjs.com/) projects.)

Comment: Hi @T.J. Crowder, in the past I tried to keep things simple by avoiding it. But now I start using React seriously and I am aware that a lot of react "plugins" (correct me if the term is wrong), such as `react-chartjs-2` which I am about to use, provide only the `npm` way. It seems to me that I cannot keep just using `<script src=""></script>` approach anymore. Is my feeling correct?..

Answer (score 1):

These two styles correspond to two different approaches of web developement.

The "first way" (npm install etc...) makes sense as a part of a "build step" where you will use a tool to build the files exposed to internet. This is suitable for big projects with a lot of source file, where you will need linting, refactoring, etc... If you want to go this way, it's not "a lot of effort" for a single project, but there is a lot to learn. You can start with the [webpack doc](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/).

The "second way" (<script ...) will allow you to directly specify the resources to load, without a "build step". This is suitable for smaller projects with a few files. It comes with the benefits that the files exposes via mainstream CDNs like cdnjs are probably already cached due to being used by other websites.

Comment: Hi @Samuel, suppose I want to switch to the "first" way and I installed bootstrap, react or whatever packages using `npm`. What should I do next? Say, how can I use the installed packages in an HTML page which will be run on clients' browser?

Comment: That's what webpack is all about. If you go step by step through the getting started of webpack (which I linked in the answer) while paying close attention, you should get a good grasp of it.

Comment: Also, as a general advice, especially if you're new to frontend, it pays off a lot to read the documentation of all the tools you will come across.

Comment: Hi @Samuel, sure let me take a look. I don't even know this thing exists before your answer...