# How can I integrate node modules in my HTML file?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

Firstly, I'd like to specify that I'm learning web development and that I'm relatively new to it. Therefore, I'm sorry if my question seems silly.

Despite my research, I can't integrate my node modules to my HTML file without having error messages in my console. I will take the Vue.js example, but this problem occurs with **any module**.

This is my HTML file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <title>Document</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my main.js file :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
```

When I do this, my console displays this error : "**Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module**"

I tried to add ' **type="module"** ' to my script tag in my HTML file, but the console displays : "**Uncaught TypeError: The specifier “vue” was a bare specifier, but was not remapped to anything. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”.**"

And finally, even if I try to fix the path, it displays : "**Loading failed for the module with source “...”.**".

What am I doing wrong ?

I thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using Vue as a framework (following some Vue tutorial) or just plain HTML?

Comment: I use it as a framework.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Vue from a plain HTML file you have to import it on the headers of the HTML file like indicated [on this tutorial](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#using-vue-from-cdn). Working snippet:

```js
const { createApp } = Vue

  createApp({
    data() {
      return {
        message: 'Hello Vue!'
      }
    }
  }).mount('#app')
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <title>Document</title>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">{{ message }}</div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

When using Vue and other frameworks it is better to stick to conventions when trying to use node modules, I cannot find a reason why you would want to work by loading scripts on your HTML file instead of following the rules on the framework and then just run `npm run build`.

### On how to load modules

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55310399/11768882) is an answer explaining how to load modules, I guess that if you tried `<script type="module" src="vue" />` `vue` there is not a path to any file exporting a module and that's why you get an error.

Comment: Thank you very much. My teacher had told me that it was better to avoid CDN links for real projects and that it was just good when learning, that's why I wanted to integrate it differently. My bad!

Comment: Nothing wrong to make mistakes when learning. Kudos to you for exploring and trying different ways. About the CDN, there is some truth to that but CDNs is not a concept limited to loading libraries or packages. And without the CDN, the way to integrate it is to build it, that process creates a bundle with all the necessary code that gets loaded in the browser when the page is visited (that's how modules are integrated)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. It helped me. I better keep learning with CDNs and come back to all of this when I'll feel more comfortable!