# Bun build Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' in browser

Tags: build, bun

I'm trying to use `bun build` to build a simple file with a command:

```
bun build ./frontindex.ts --outdir ./out  --sourcemap=external --target=browser
```

This is the content of the typescript: file I'm trying to build:

```
function hellotest(){
    console.log("HELLOOOOOOO");
}

export async function uploadFile(){
    const request = new Request("https://localhost:3002/uploadfile");
    let response = await fetch(request);
    console.log(response.status); 
}
```

What I get as a result of this build is:

```
// frontindex.ts
async function uploadFile() {
  const request = new Request("https://localhost:3002/uploadfile");
  let response = await fetch(request);
  console.log(response.status);
}
export {
  uploadFile
};

//# debugId=44CBE69BCCC3BC3264756e2164756e21
```

When I open the browser, I get an error saying:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

I don't understand why it builds the way it does? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you using the result in the browser? Are you treating the file as a module or just JavaScript?

Comment: Just javascript, I am importing it with <script></script> in the index.html. @scrhartley

Comment: You need to tell the browser it's importing a module, not plain old JS: `<script type="module" src="testfile1.js" />`. As on alternative, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55310227/cant-figure-out-how-to-import-modules-in-browser-with-javascript) or [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_modules.asp) or [here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/using-javascript-modules-in-the-browser-2c55bfc5f5e9). Perhaps look into [import maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#importing_modules_using_import_maps).